# Powershell - error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ICertificatePolicy' could not be found - failure in gitlab pipeline

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to reuse this powershell script which performs smoketest post deployment. The script works just fine when I run locally on the build server but when I try to run through my gitlab pipeline it fails with error: **add-type @"(3,36): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ICertificatePolicy' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {**

**Code that is erroring out**:

```
add-type @"
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
    public bool CheckValidationResult(
        ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
        WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
        return true;
    }
}
"@
$AllProtocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12'
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $AllProtocols
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy

$HTTP_Status_Timeout = 0
$HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
```

**My understanding so far**:
Based on my research I tried to compare the Powershell version of my build server vs gitlab pipeline

*Build server*

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14393.4583
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14393.4583
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
```

*gitlab pipeline*

```
PSVersion                      7.2.4
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.2.4
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.14393
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0.}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

As I understand the piece of code does not work in poweshell 7

**What I have tried so far**:
I found out a similar issue here: [PowerShell - Add-Type Issue trying to do REST call without self-signed cert issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70863524/powershell-add-type-issue-trying-to-do-rest-call-without-self-signed-cert-issu)

And I tried to add `-SkipCertificateCheck` but that did not work.
I also tried to force the powershell to use version 5.0 by adding `#Requires -Version 5.0` to my pipeline code but that also dis not work

I also tried the code block but that results in a different error

```
$certCallback = @"
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
public class ServerCertificateValidationCallback
{
    public static void Ignore()
    {
        if(ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback ==null)
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
                delegate
                (
                    Object obj, 
                    X509Certificate certificate, 
                    X509Chain chain, 
                    SslPolicyErrors errors
                )
                {
                    return true;
                };
        }
    }
}
"@
Add-Type $certCallback

$AllProtocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12,Tls13'
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $AllProtocols
[ServerCertificateValidationCallback]::Ignore()
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy
```

The above code is resulting in error: **Exception setting "SecurityProtocol": "The requested security protocol is not supported."**
I tried to check the .Net version and the following versions are available

```
PSChildName : v2.0.50727
Version     : 2.0.50727.4927
PSChildName : v3.0
Version     : 3.0.30729.4926
PSChildName : Windows Communication Foundation
Version     : 3.0.4506.4926
PSChildName : Windows Presentation Foundation
Version     : 3.0.6920.4902
PSChildName : v3.5
Version     : 3.5.30729.4926
PSChildName : Client
Version     : 4.7.02053
PSChildName : Full
Version     : 4.7.02053
PSChildName : Client
Version     : 4.0.0.0
```

**What I think could help**:

`Option1` - Making changes in the script which is compatible to run in Powershell 7.2
`Option2` - Force my pipeline job to use powershell version 5

Although I think the 2 options can help resolving the problem but I am not sure if it is the right approach. Hence Request your guidance in finding the right solution/guidance in resolving this issue.

Comment: [`ICertificatePolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.icertificatepolicy?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=net-7.0) doesn't exist in .NET Core. So that explains your error. If you want to go with that code you must run it in pwsh 5.1

Comment: You have your answer in this GH comment https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7092#issuecomment-398005195 if you want to do it from Pwsh Core (.NET Core)

Comment: This sounds like a TLS issue. System.Net.SecurityProtocolType is using Net Library (same as c#).   Only TLS 1.2 and 1.3 are validate (others are obsolete).  Net Library before 4.7.2 did TLS in the Net Library.  Newer versions Net are using the OS for TLS.  What I think is happening is PS 5,0 is use Net library while 7.2 is using OS.  Depending on encryption mode in certificate will determine if PS 5.0 or PS 7.2 will work.  Older certificates will not work with new versions of TLS.  Old Net library also doesn't work with newer certificates.  Net doesn't support all encryption modes.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I used `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` as a replacement to `ICertificatePolicy` but also failed with a similar error.  This is what I used as a replacement `public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ServerCertificateValidationCallback`
Please suggest if I am not using it in the correct form or anything else I can try

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I have tried your suggested code and I have edited my original post with your suggestion but that also is not resolving the issue.  Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to resolve the issue and found 2 solutions to my problem

1. Changed the gitlab-runner pointing from `pwsh` to `powershell` which will use the desktop/os version of powershell
2. Curl can let you make a web-request and capture the return code. Here is the command `curl $url | select-object statuscode`

Hopefully this helps someone!